# isBlank() removal elastic search 1.4

Tags: elasticsearch

I am finding the alternative for StringUtils which is coming from import org.elasticsearch.common.lang3.StringUtils; as it was used on elastic search 1.4.3 
but not any alternative for elastic search 2.4

```
if (StringUtils.isBlank(refNo)) {
  throw new InvalidParameterException("SHIPMENT_REF_NO_CANNOT_BE_BLANK");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to import the [Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/) library and then use the [`org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.isBlank()` static method](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-release/src-html/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#line.296).

The Elasticsearch codebase used to embed that library and a few others but they (rightly) decided to get rid of that in order to deliver a cleaner package.

Comment: I have com.springsource.org.apache.commons.lang-2.1.0.jar in by libraries. should i use this?

Comment: If you can find `StringUtils.isBlank()` in there then you're good

Comment: Dont they give conflict previous one is from elastic search and now using it from org.springsource

Comment: You're simply using another class than you were previously. I don't see any way this could conflict. Since ES 2.4 doesn't provide `StringUtils` anymore, you might just as well use it from another library